# Find the equation of the curve $g(x)$ in the graph.

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

The given graph is given as :

[image: this image]

Since , I have to find the equation for $g(x)$ , and since $g(x)$ is parabolic , I figured that the equation used will be
Let $g(x) = y$,
then the equation becomes
$(y-k)^2 = 4a(x-h)$ , which further on solving for y becomes $y=\sqrt{4a(x-h)}+k$ , hence we have three unknowns $a,h$ and $k$.

I can't figure out how to proceed from here , also what help (if any) does $f(x)$ provides me with?

Comment: $f$ is completely useless lol. Have you got the original question?

Comment: Oh yeah and you can sub the coordinates of any point that $g$ goes through to obtain some equations which you can then use to solve for $a, h, k$.

Comment: @SenZen i have provided the question in the image

Comment: The purpose of $f$ is to serve as a parent function, so the way forward is to transform $f$ to get $g$. If you look closely, you can see that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. The function is shifted four units left and five units down, and is scaled by some factor. What changes would you need to make to $f(x)$ to make these transformations?

Comment: @Stephen Goree thanks for the input . how do you think i can incorporate the scaling factor in $g(x)$ ? I don't know much about it.

Comment: @TanishqYadav $f(4)=2$, so look for some value of $x$ for which $g(x)$ is analogous to  $f(4)$ and apply the necessary scaling to $f(x)$ to make it fit the graph of $g(x)$ after you've made the translations leftward and downward.

Comment: The main problem is that the graph doesn't clearly show that whether the curve $g(x)$ has been shifted 5 units down or 6 units down . Is it all left to assumptions ?

Comment: It is clearly not 6 units down.. If it were 6 units, the bottom of $g$ would be on the horizontal blue line corresponding to the horizontal line $y= -6$.

Comment: I think the graph is not correctly shown. Because on reverse-engineering the answer , I've found out that the vertex of $g(x)$ is (-4,-6).

Comment: What was that answer?

Answer (score 1):

From the graph, $g(x)$ passes through the points $(6,6) (0,2) (-2, 0)$. Insert these points into the equation $(y-k)^2=4a(x-h)$ :
$$(6-k)^2=4a(6-h)$$ $$(2-k)^2=4a(0-h)$$ $$(0-k)^2=4a(-2-h)$$
Subtract the 2nd and 3rd equations from the 1st, using the identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ on the LHS :
$$(4)(8-2k)=4a(6) \implies 4-k=3a$$ $$(6)(6-2k)=4a(8) \implies 9-3k=8a$$
Multiply the 4th eqn by 3 and subtract the 5th eqn to find $a$, then back-substitute to find $k, h$ :
$$3=a$$ $$k=4-3a=4-9=-5$$ $$-4ah=(2-k)^2 \implies -12h=49 \implies h=-\frac{49}{12}$$